# Feeding list position as parameter to arcpy.SymDiff_analysis function

Tags: python, arcpy

New to python.
I have two feature datasets, Input features (NewDemoFC) and Update Features (ExistingFC) with 5 feature classes each. One set contains demolished features, the other set contains all active features. The objective is to compare the two and wherever the demolished features (from NewDemoFC) overlap with an active feature (from ExistingFC), delete the overlapping active features (from ExistingFC) and output a new feature class.

I want to use the while function and be able to feed a particular position from the list for both input features and update feature parameters. Also would like to maintain the same names and order for output feature class names.

Trying to achieve the results of the below model for a dataset with multiple files as the SymDiff_analysis tool doesn't work on more than one FC as input, unless you add each feature class as a line item, specifying input, output and any intermediate temporary files. This is not practical for a dataset with 100 odd feature classes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItFKn.png)

CODE IS AS UNDER

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Set environment to generate new input feature class list and count 
arcpy.env.workspace = "T:\eALP_Update.gdb\Point_DemoNew"
NewDemoFC = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
NewDemoFCCount = len(NewDemoFC)

# Set environment to generate existing feature class list
arcpy.env.workspace = "T:\eALP_Update.gdb\Point_InputExisting"
ExistingFC = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

E_PointFeatures_ActiveOnly =  []

i = 0
#arcpy.env.workspace = "T:\eALP_Update.gdb\Point_ActiveExisting"

while i < NewDemoFCCount:

    # Process: Symmetrical Difference (2)
    arcpy.SymDiff_analysis(NewDemoFC[i], ExistingFC[i], E_PointFeatures_ActiveOnly[i], "ALL", "0.01 Feet")
    i = i + 1
```

ERROR I GET IS AS UNDER

> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\intpyapp.py", line 345, in OnFileRun
> > >           scriptutils.RunScript(None, None, showDlg)
> > >         File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 353, in RunScript
> > >           del **main**.**file**
> > >       AttributeError: **file**
> > >       5
> > >       [u'Demo_New_UTILITYPOINT', u'Demo_New_ROADPOINT', u'Demo_New_AIRPORTSIGN', u'Demo_New_AIRPORTCONTROLPOINT', u'Demo_New_AIRFIELDLIGHT']
> > >       5
> > >       [u'UtilityPoint', u'RoadPoint', u'AirportSign', u'AirportControlPoint', u'AirfieldLight']
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
> > >           exec codeObject in **main**.**dict**
> > >         File "T:\Data\GOAA\eALPUpdates\Point_2-SymmetricalDifferenceOnly.py", line 41, in 
> > >           arcpy.SymDiff_analysis(NewDemoFC[i], ExistingFC[i], E_PointFeatures_ActiveOnly[i], "ALL", "0.01 Feet")
> > >       IndexError: list index out of range
> > >       [Dbg]>>>

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use a for loop that iterates over each feature class to avoid the odd indexing process you have going on inside your call to arcpy.SymDiff. For example, the use of i to index E_PointFeatures_ActiveOnly (an empty list) as an output path won't work. To do this the way you want to, you'll need to dynamically generate file names. Make sure that the output folder is empty when you do this to avoid naming conflicts. The code you have also duplicates everything for each folder, so we can define functions to eliminate that, that way you can re-use it easily. Lastly, you really want to avoid altering global variables like arcpy.env.workspace multiple times - the function below for this is really verbose, but since it's a function, you only have to do it once! I'll assume you have access to arcgis version >= 10.1 The following code is long and untested, but I imagine it should do the trick:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "T:\eALP_Update.gdb\Point_ActiveExisting"

def getFCs(folderOne, folderTwo):
  """Get feature classes from two folders"""
  from os.path import join
  x = []
  y = []
  folders = [folderOne, folderTwo]
  for folder in folders:
    for paths, directory, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(
             folder,
             topdown=True,
             followlinks=False,
             datatype='FeatureClass',
             type='ALL'):
      for file in filenames:
        if folder == folder[0]:
          x.append(join(directory, file))
        else:
          y.append(join(directory, file))
  return x, y

def batchSymDiff(inFolder, updateFolder, joinAttr, clusterTolerance):
  """Performs SymDiff analysis for every feature in a set of folders"""
  inFeatures, updateFeatures = getFCs(inFolder, updateFolder)
  for fc1, fc2 in zip(inFeatures, updateFeatures):
    output = fc2.replace(".shp", "_sym.shp") # this naming pattern assumes ".shp" ending
    arcpy.SymDiff_analysis(fc1, fc2, output, joinAttr, clusterTolerance)

# set variables for batch process
inFolder = "T:\eALP_Update.gdb\Point_DemoNew"
updateFolder = "T:\eALP_Update.gdb\Point_InputExisting"
joinAttr = "ALL"
clusterTolerance = "0.01"

# execute batchSymDiff
batchSymDiff(inFolder, updateFolder, joinAttr, clusterTolerance)
```

This code is probably more verbose than it *has* to be, but doing it this way means you can avoid changing global env vars over and over - a risky business since the errors it causes are really difficult to diagnose sometimes - and it makes your code reusable. Also note that it eliminates the need to use a "manual" counter (i). Hope it helps! I suggest testing the code on test data first.